# ECW plugin QGIS 2.18 for mac?

Tags: qgis-plugins, mac, ecw

How can one install the ECW plugin for QGIS 2.18 for mac? I would simple step by step for this.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  A good question should show some degree of research and attempt.  What have you tried, and what happens when you try it?  Are you having difficulty installing the plugin, or do you just not have a plugin to install (you do now as there is one linked from the Duplicate Q&A)